# Obtener el nombre de un fichero sin extension y sin la ruta c#

Tags: c#

Tengo en una variable, la ruta del directorio. Quiero comparar si el nombre que le voy a dar al archivo, ya esta dentro de ese directorio.

```
 private int comprobarNombre(string outputName, string outpuPath)
    {
        int contadorAux = 0;
        string auxNombreRepetido;
        //Try catch por si introducimos antes el nombre que la carpeta
        try
        {
            string[] ubicacion = Directory.GetFiles(outpuPath);
            for (int i = 0; i < ubicacion.Length; i++)
            {
                auxNombreRepetido = ubicacion[i];

                if (auxNombreRepetido.Equals(outputName))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Repetido");
                    contadorAux++;
                }
            }
            return contadorAux;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Introduce una carpeta antes del nombre");
        }
        return contadorAux;
    }
```

Ya no se como hacerlo. He probado con split, pero me coge la ruta del fichero+nombre+extension. He probado tambien, con un subString, pero me pasa lo mismo, y he probado esto ultimo.

```
string fileName = @"C:\mydir\myfile.ext";
string path = @"C:\mydir\";
string result;

result = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
```

Pero no me funciona, (imagino que es porque no pongo @"C:\mydir\myfile.ext", ya que la ruta es alternativa, la guardo en una variable que usuario da).

Comment: Con el `GetFileNameWithoutExtension`debería funcionarte y sólo darte el nombre del archivo. puedes poner un ejemplo de la ruta que te da el usuario, la cual no te funciona con este método?

Comment: C:\Users\becas.primero\Desktop\test Al usar GetFileNameWithoutExtensiondebería me aparece, "string" no contiene una definicion para GetFileNameWithoutExtensiondebería ni un metodo de extension accesible GetFileNameWithoutExtensiondebería  que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "string" (¿Falta alguna directiva, using o una refenrencia de emsamblado?) Tengo puesto using System.IO;

Comment: Utiliza el método 'File.Exists' para saber si el archivo existe (con o sin extensión) . [Referencia](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: result = File.Exists(outpuPath.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(auxNombreRepetido)); Sigo teniendo el mismo problema con GetFileNameWithoutExtension

Comment: `outpuPath.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` es incorrecto. Debes poner siempre `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`. El ultimo código que pones en tu pregunta [funciona perfectamente](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sryvFV)

Comment: Estaba poniendo outPath porque es el nombre mi variable, la que contiene el nombre de la ruta

Comment: Ya,pero es incorrecto. El método es `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`, y el nombre de tu variable(que debe ser la ruta a un archivo) se pasa como parámetro al metodo.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, ya me funciona... Pensaba que tendria que poner el nombre de mi variable. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: De todas maneras, deduzco de tu pregunta que lo que quieres es simplemente comprobar si existe un archivo con el mismo nombre en la ruta. Para ello como te han dicho es mejor que uses `File.Exists` y le pases la ruta completa con el nombre de archivo que quieres crear. Si devuelve true, el nombre ya esta en uso